# How to combine two text file as one?

Tags: python, text

I have two text files. I want to combine some of their columns in a new text file.

I am trying this, but it is not working:

```
with open('1','r') as first:
    with open('2', 'r') as second:
        data1 = first.readlines()
        for line in data1:
            output = [(item.strip(), line.split(' ')[2]) for item in second]
            f = open("1+2","w")
            f.write("%s  %s\n" .format(output))
            f.close()
```

first text file that I have:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Second text file that I have:

```
1 3
2 5
5 7
7 3
```

I want a new file with the column in first file and second column in second file, which is like this:

```
1 3
2 5
3 7
4 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the respective line pairs, and concatenate the first column of first file with the second column of the second:

```
with open('file_1.txt') as f1, open('file_2.txt') as f2, open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fr:
    for line in ("{} {}".format(l1.rstrip('\n'), l2.split(maxsplit=1)[1]) for l1, l2 in zip(f1, f2)):
        fr.write(line)
```

If you're sure that the columns are separated by a single space, you can also use `str.partition` like:

```
l2.partition(' ')[-1]
```

**Example:**

```
In [28]: with open('file_1.txt') as f1, open('file_2.txt') as f2, open('new_file.txt', 'w') as fr:
    ...:     for line in ("{} {}".format(l1.rstrip('\n'), l2.split(maxsplit=1)[1]) for l1, l2 in zip(f1, f2)):
    ...:         fr.write(line)
    ...:     

In [29]: cat new_file.txt
1 3
2 5
3 7
4 3
```

As an aside, when you don't have same number of rows in both files, and you want to keep operating on the longest one, you can look at `itertools.zip_longest` instead of `zip`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your both file are data file, you can use the `numpy` module.

- [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) loads text file in array.
- [`savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) saves an array in a text file. You can also specify the format of number saved with the `fmt` option.

Here the code:

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.loadtxt("file1.txt")
data2 = np.loadtxt("file2.txt")
print(data1)
# [1. 2. 3. 4.]
print(data2)
# [[1. 3.]
#  [2. 5.]
#  [5. 7.]
#  [7. 3.]]

data2[:, 0] = data1
print(data2)
# [[1. 3.]
#  [2. 5.]
#  [3. 7.]
#  [4. 3.]]
np.savetxt('output.txt', data2, fmt="%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import izip

with open("file1.txt") as textfile1, open("file2.txt") as textfile2, open('output.txt', 'w') as out: 
    for x, y in izip(textfile1, textfile2):
        x = x.strip()
        y = y.split(" ")[1].strip()
        print("{0} {1}".format(x, y))
        out.write("{0} {1}\n".format(x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many interesting answers as to *how to do that*, but none of them show how to fix your code. I find it better for learning when we understand our own mistakes, rather than get a solution ;)

---

Tuple in the same line has object names the other way around - you want line (from 1st file) stripped and item (from 2nd) split and took second element (that would be `[1]`)

With those small changes (and others, described in comments), we get:

```
with open('1','r') as first:
    with open('2', 'r') as second:
        #data1 = first.readlines() #don't do that, iterate over the file
        for line in first: #changed
            output = [(line.strip(), item.split(' ')[1]) for item in second]
            f = open("1+2","a") #use mode "a" for appending - otherwise you're overwriting your data!
            f.write("{}  {}".format(output)) # don't mix python2 and python3 syntax, removed extra newline
            f.close()
```

But it's still wrong. Why? Because `for item in second` - you're parsing **whole** second file here. In the first ever line from 1st file.

We need to change it so that we only take one element. I'd recommend you [read this question and explanations about iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration).

Now let's apply this knowledge: `second` is an iterator. We only need one element from it and we need to do it manually (because we're in another loop - looping over 2 things at once is a tricky thing), so we'll be using `next(second)`:

```
with open('1','r') as first:
    with open('2', 'r') as second:
        for line in first: 
            item = next(second)
            output = (line.strip(), item.split(' ')[1]) #no list comprehension here
            f = open("1+2","a") 
            f.write("{}  {}".format(*output)) #you have to unpack the tuple
            f.close()
```

[Explanation about unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) - basically, when you pass just `output`, Python sees it as once element and doesn't know what to do with the other `{}`. You have to say "hey, treat this iterable (in this case: 2-element tuple) as single elements, not a whole" and that's how this `*` does. :)